# last list item appears in new list after adding and

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and having issues with this code. I'm using a for loop to cycle through the list and I need it to print the word `'and'` before the last item. I have got it to work, but not the way I want it to.

Instead of `'and ' + last item` appearing inside the list, it appears outside of it when I print. Can someone give me a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
for i in range(1):
    print(listToPrint[0:-1], end =', ' + 'and ' + listToPrint[-1])
```

Comment: The slice of a list returns a list. `listToPrint[0:-1]` is a list, so the closing square brace appears before the `','`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I thought that's what was happening, but I don't know how else to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `str.join()` a slice of your words sans the last one and print the last one in line:

```
print("{}, and {}".format(", ".join(listToPrint[:-1]), listToPrint[-1]))
```

Comment: I made one minor change print("{}, and {}".format(", ".join(listToPrint[:-1]), listToPrint[-1])), but this is what I'm looking for. Can you explain this code or tell me where I can learn what this is?

Comment: @KennyFreeman - you can also use your original statement as: `print(", ".join(listToPrint[:-1]), end=", and " + listToPrint[-1] + "\n")
`, but _(opinion time)_ it's better to control your output formatting whenever you can and I find it more readable anyway.

Comment: I like the way you originally did it. I just didn't know you could format like you did with a string. What is that called?

Comment: @KennyFreeman - [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is the native and a preferred way to do complex string formatting in Python. You can read more on its use at [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what you seem to be wanting.

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
listToPrint[-1] = "and " + listToPrint[-1]

print(listToPrint)
```